# Как задать минимальную длину дуги в круговой диаграмме?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Создал круговую диаграмму, но некоторые сектора настолько маленькие, что на них невозможно кликнуть. Скажите, как задать минимальную длину сектора?

```
   var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .padAngle(0)
                    .innerRadius(this.ARC_RADIUS_INNER)
                    .outerRadius(this.ARC_RADIUS_OUTER);

            // Создадим g в нашей выборке, для группировки svg
            var pie_area = chart_area
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.CHART_WIDTH / 2 + ',' + this.CHART_HEIGHT / 2 + ')');

            // Создаем компоновку круговой диаграммы
            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                    .startAngle(Math.PI / 4)
                    .endAngle(Math.PI * 2 + Math.PI / 4)
                    .value(function (d) {
                        return size = d.size > MIN_WIDTH_ANG ? d.size : MIN_WIDTH_ANG;
                    });

   // Выберем все элементы <g> с классом 'slice'
        var arcs = pie_area.selectAll('.slice')
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'slice');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Круговая диаграмма это не просто картинка, в ней размеры дуг пропорциональны доле, которую визуализирует эта дуга, не корректно ее делать больше - это нарушает баланс.

Быть может Вам просто надо для значений меньше определенного порога увеличить активную зону за счет добавления прозрачного бордера пикселя в 3 и поместив такие элементы "наверх"?

Между красным и зеленым сектором есть очень маленький желтый - попробуйте на него навести мышь

```js
let overlap = 0.2, 
    duration = 1000,
    count = 2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
    data = [100,2,200,800].map(d => ({value: d})),
    total = data.reduce((a,e) => a+e.value,0);

let svg = d3.select('svg');
let pie = d3.pie().sort(null); 
let arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(70).outerRadius(85);

svg.selectAll('path')
   .data(pie(data.map(d => d.value)))
   .enter()
   .append('path')
   .attr("fill", (d, i) => `hsl(${i*66.5},75%,45%)`)
   .attr('d', arc)
   .on('mouseover', d => text.innerHTML = d.value)
   .each(function(d) {
      if (d.value>total/100)
        d3.select(this).lower()
      else
        d3.select(this).attr('stroke-width', 5)
                       .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
   })
```

```css
path:hover {
  fill: black;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" height="90vh">
<text id="text" font-size="60px" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"></text>
</svg>
```

PS: В вашем коде синтаксис от старой третьей версии. Я сделал пример на 5